How to publish all nupkg files from the folder using TeamCity
I have a library which consists of several nuget packages. For example:

MyPackage.1.0.0.0.nupkg
MyPackage.Core.1.0.0.0.nupkg
MyPackage.UI.1.0.0.0.nupkg

Is it possible to push all of these packages to nuget.org in one step using TeamCity?
Here is the screenshot with my settings:

